how do i develop an spl token 22 with transferfee config?
disclaimer: im very new to programming. how do i develop a an spl token 2022 in anchor with transferfee config enabled, while disabling mint and freeze? i checked the solana docs but the method it showed me didnt teach me how to create it via anchor which i need to implement logic to burn part of the tax and disabled mint and freeze. if transferfee config doesnt support functionality to burn part of the tax, is it possible to have 2 tax wallets for transferfeeconfig (one for burning and one with my wallet address)?

This doesn't answer your exact question, but it might be easier to create the token with CLI instead of Anchor.
$ spl-token --program-id TokenzQdBNbLqP5VEhdkAS6EPFLC1PHnBqCXEpPxuEb create-token --transfer-fee 50 5000

This disables freezing, but sets the mint authority to the default key. Once you've minted all of the tokens, you can disable minting with:
$ spl-token authorize <MINT_ID> mint --disable

If you want to burn part of the transfer fee, you can create a permissionless program that will withdraw fees and burn them, and then set the withdraw withheld authority to a PDA for that program. That way anyone can run a crank to burn fees.
Adapted from https://spl.solana.com/token-2022/extensions#transfer-fees and https://spl.solana.com/token#example-create-a-non-fungible-token
